# Is there a way to create an immutable value in a document with Vespa

Tags: vespa

Is is possible to create a new Vespa doc and have one key/value pair immutable for the life of that doc?

Answer (score 0):

There's no build-in support for that so you'd need to create a [document processor](https://docs.vespa.ai/en/document-processing.html) to reject updates to that field.

If you also want to reject attempts to put the whole document again, the processor would have to use the [document API](https://docs.vespa.ai/en/document-api-guide.html) to check if each document already existed. That is doable but would slow down your write rate.